# Rotation of state-transition matrix to a chosen parametric form

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, linear-transformations, maximum-likelihood

When using EM algorithm for estimating the state matrices ($\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{C}$) of a linear state-space model (as shown below),
\begin{align*}
x_k &= \mathbf{A} x_{k-1} + w_k\\
y_k &= \mathbf{C} x_{k} + v_k
\end{align*} I found that the state matrix $\mathbf{A}$ loses its *parameterization*. What I mean by that is, I start with an initial estimate of the form $\mathbf{A}^{(0)} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & I \\ E(\theta) & F(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}$ but I lose this form of $\mathbf{A}$ after a couple iterations of EM. My question is: given a fully populated EM estimate of $\hat{\mathbf{A}} = \begin{bmatrix}
\hat{A}_{11} & \hat{A}_{12} \\ \hat{A}_{21} & \hat{A}_{22}
\end{bmatrix}$, is it possible to rotate $\hat{\mathbf{A}}$ to atleast have the structure of $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & I \\ \hat{E} & \hat{F}
\end{bmatrix}$ ?

Note: I don't have the knowledge of $\hat{E}$ and $\hat{F}$. All I know is $\hat{\mathbf{A}}$ and the form of $[0 \;\;I]$ of the top block of parameterized $\mathbf{A}$

Comment: Does EM preserve the rank of $A$?

Comment: Yes it does in my case.